# Iptables - Block https response only

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I'm quite new to Linux and using `iptables`. Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

1. I have an ASP.net client that talks with a web service hosted through web-logic on linux. The communication is over SSL.
2. What I am trying accomplish using `iptables` is only block the response back to the client.
3. So the client makes a web service call, the web service processes the request and replies back to the client.
4. I want the web service to receive the request but block its response back to the client.

What I did for test purposes was flush all the rules from `iptables`. I created default policies for `ACCEPT` on the `INPUT`, `OUTPUT` and `FORWARD` chains. Next I added a rule to the `OUTPUT` chain to `DROP` anything which has the source IP of the client.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -s client_ip_address -j DROP
```

Apparently, this made no difference. I can call the web service from the client and still receive a response.

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: Don't you want `-s client_ip_address` to be `-d client_ip_address`, since you want to block connecting out to the client?

Comment: I tried that as well but doesn't work. Also I'm not sure that it should be the destination (-d) because the TCP stream is not originating from the host which has the web service. The response would go back on the same TCP stream that originating from the client so I am thinking I would want to block the output to that source. Am I making sense here?

Comment: I'm just digging here, but what if you try adding `--state ESTABLISHED`? (I'd say with `-d`, but you can also try `-s`).

Comment: If you block the response, the HTTP user agent will ultimately hang. What's the point of doing *that*?

Comment: Tried that with both -d and -s ... still didn't work. I used "iptables -A OUTPUT -d client_ip_address -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j DROP.

Comment: @j0rgensen ... thats exactly what I am trying to test. Timeout situations or hangs when it does not get a response.

Comment: What you are trying is not possible, at least not with iptables and SSL. Without SSL you could use the string patch to match your GET/POST/whatever requests but not with SSL. There are no modules to match binary content or ssl packets even if it would be sufficient though to match the outgoing SSL Application Data packets and drop them. The client will hang until the configured timeout is reached though.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what exactly do you want to accomplish. If you want to simulate network timeout use this:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d clientip  -j DROP
```

it will silently drop all packets from the server to the client.

If you want to let tcp handshake happen and then to kill the connection (might be useful or you can just activate the above rule later) use this:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d clientip -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK SYN,ACK -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d clientip  -j DROP
```

If you want to simulate closed port (service not running) use:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s clientip  -j REJECT
```

it will send ICMP Destination unreachable message back to the client.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have a rule earlier in the OUTPUT chain that allows all ESTABLISHED and RELATED connections - this is quite common.  If such a rule is there, it will be matched before a DROP rule you put in with -A.  Try putting your DROP rule as early as possible in the OUTPUT chain:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -d clientip  -j DROP
```

will put the rule at the very top of the chain.